# Additional apt sources folder

Tags: apt

I would like to define an additional `sources.list.d` folder just for my user; something like `~/sources.list.d` so that I sync and use these across my machines.

Is it possible to do something like this with apt ?

Comment: So, you want to upgrade some packages only for your user?

Comment: Not really... I want to sync some sources across machines. The problem isn't really that I want anything private, it's just that when I add a PPA or something on one machine, I end up missing stuff on another cause that machine didn't have the updated sources  and I end up troubleshooting versioning issues. Does that make sense ?

Comment: So, your question is [Syncing apt-get installations between multiple computers](http://askubuntu.com/q/20916/147044)?

Comment: Indeed... I think that address the question. Thanks

Comment: So, it's a duplicate, let's close it :)

Comment: Agreed (making up characters)